# Modify the existing pandas DataFrame and add/ delete columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the following info,

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6661 entries, 0 to 6660
Data columns (total 4 columns):
currency       6661 non-null object
port           6661 non-null object
supplier_id    6661 non-null int64
value          6661 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 260.2+ KB
None
```

These are the columns,

```
[u'currency' u'port' u'supplier_id' u'value']
```

when I print, I get the value as following,

```
     currency   port  supplier_id     value
0         USD  CNAQG           35  118.8344
1         USD  CNAQG           19  121.0082
2         USD  CNAQG           49   86.9520
3         USD  CNAQG           54  112.3130
4         USD  CNAQG          113  113.7622
5         USD  CNAQG            5  114.4868
6         USD  CNAQG           55  111.5884
7         USD  CNAQG           81  117.3852
8         USD  CNAQG            2  111.5884
9         USD  CNAQG           10  119.5590
10        USD  CNAQG           56  105.0670
11        USD  CNAQG           14  119.5590
12        USD  CNAQG            4  115.9360
13        USD  CNAQG            7  119.5590
14        USD  CNAQG           74  127.5296
```

I would like to add a new column `country` and get the country name from the `port`. If the port name starts with `CN`, the name of the country will be `CHINA` and if the port name starts with `US`, the name of the country will be `USA`. Afterwards, the columns  `currency   port  supplier_id` needs to be `deleted` from the `DF` and the indexes suppose to be the same.

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by dict `d` first 2 characters of column port by [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str). Last remove columns by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
print (df)
   currency   port  supplier_id     value
0       USD  CNAQG           35  118.8344
1       USD  CNAQG           19  121.0082
2       USD  CNAQG           49   86.9520
3       USD  CNAQG           54  112.3130
4       USD  CNAQG          113  113.7622
5       USD  CNAQG            5  114.4868
6       USD  CNAQG           55  111.5884
7       USD  CNAQG           81  117.3852
8       USD  CNAQG            2  111.5884
9       USD  CNAQG           10  119.5590
10      USD  CNAQG           56  105.0670
11      USD  CNAQG           14  119.5590
12      USD  CNAQG            4  115.9360
13      USD  CNAQG            7  119.5590
14      USD  USAQG           74  127.5296 <-last value is changed
```

```
d = {'CN':'CHINA', 'US':'USA'}

df['country'] = df.port.str[:2].map(d)
df = df.drop(['currency','port','supplier_id'], axis=1)
print (df)
       value country
0   118.8344   CHINA
1   121.0082   CHINA
2    86.9520   CHINA
3   112.3130   CHINA
4   113.7622   CHINA
5   114.4868   CHINA
6   111.5884   CHINA
7   117.3852   CHINA
8   111.5884   CHINA
9   119.5590   CHINA
10  105.0670   CHINA
11  119.5590   CHINA
12  115.9360   CHINA
13  119.5590   CHINA
14  127.5296     USA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe, would you mind to come for chat ? I knocked you over there.

Comment: sure, no problem. Some problems?

Comment: Yes, and I cant post more questions before 90 minutes here. Do you see the chat I write ?

Comment: can you post link to chat?

Comment: Sure, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137457/discussion-between-are-and-jezrael

Comment: May be `Skype` would be better option `chaklader304161`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137562/discussion-between-are-and-jezrael).

Comment: I see your new question, can you join chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137562/discussion-between-are-and-jezrael

Comment: Yes, can you join chat ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137562/discussion-between-are-and-jezrael ?